# How To Make Submenu Stay Visible After It Is Clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have build a admin panel where in sidebar there is submenu with menu But the problem I'm facing is i want to stay visible when i cliked one of the submenu..But it again going to main menu.

How to stay visible for the submenu cliked..any suggestion or help with code please?

```
 <div id="sidebar"><a href="#" class="visible-phone"><i class="icon icon-home"></i> Dashboard</a>
        <ul>
            <li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Members</span></a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Create Member</a></li>               
                        <li><a href="">Member List</a></li>                
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Payroll</span></a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Create Monthly Payroll</a></li>               
                        <li><a href="">Edit Monthly Payroll</a></li>                           
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="submenu"> <a href="#"><i class="icon icon-list"></i> <span>Report</span></a>
                <ul>
                        <li><a href="">Manager Monthly Report</a></li>               
                        <li><a href="">Employee Monthly Report</a></li>                      
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add the relevant CSS, and JavaScript?

Comment: creating a fiddle here be helpful here